# Kernighan and Ritchie Exercise 2-2 Debugging?

Tags: c

I am working through K&R (2nd edition) for my own edification and encountered the following exercise (exercise 2-2 p42):

```
Write a loop equivalent to the following without using && or ||:

   for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; ++i)
           s[i] = c;
```

This was my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* write a loop equivalent to the following without using && or ||

   for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; ++i)
           s[i] = c;
*/

int main()
{
    int counter = 0, lim = 1000;
    int s[lim], c;

    while(counter < lim-1)
    {
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
        {
            while(c != EOF)
            {
                s[counter] = c;
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the indented loops and therefore the entire program to exit normally once it encountered a newline character (`'\n'`) or an EOF character (`Ctrl-d` on my Linux machine), but to my surprise it happily soldiers on. I tried to debug it using gdb but still could not figure it out.

What am I not seeing?

Addendum: I tried to reverse the sequence of tests the while loops perform and added an if statement to break out of the outer loop if `c == '\n'` but am still not seeing it! I am also having difficulty trying to run GDB entering text into the command line and simultaneously printing the value of `c`, even when I tried to link gdb to the pid of a running copy of the executable. I realize that there are probably other ways to solve this exercise, e.g. setting an `OK_TO_EXECUTE` flag or variable that is true only if all three conditions are met, but I am bothered by the fact that I seem unable to find the bug in a seemingly simple program. This is precisely why I am returning to K&R to go through the book more thoroughly and to solve the exercises properly.

Redone code (still buggy!!!):

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* write a loop equivalent to the following without using && or ||

   for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; ++i)
           s[i] = c;
*/

int main()
{
    int counter = 0, lim = 1000;
    int s[lim], c;



    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    { 
        if ( c == '\n')
            break;

        while(c != '\n')
        {
            while(counter < lim-1)
            {
                s[counter] = c;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

SOLVED! - I think! I think I have finally figured it out. The inner loops as written in my redone solution will still loop endlessly or at lease till `lim` is reached. I added break
statements and think I am on my way to a solution.

I am still wrestling with how to run gdb on this problem though; enter the command line entries AND `print` the value of `c`. Linking gdb to the pid of the executable still did not work as expected. I even posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865614/how-do-i-run-gdb-enter-text-into-the-command-line-and-see-how-the-executable-tr) regarding gdb.

Comment: Go to http://lysator.liu.se/c and check out the C tutorials listed there. They are quite dated (almost as much as K&R2), but still very relevant.

Comment: "What am I not seeing?" -- It's not possible for anyone else to know. When I look at that code, I see loops not doing a `getchar`, which is obviously wrong. I don't know how anyone can look at it and *not* see that. It's intuitively obvious to me that there must be only one loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added loops that didn't exist in the original ... that's conceptually and logically wrong. The most obvious solution uses `break`:

```
for (i = 0; i < lim-1; ++i)
{
    c = getchar();
    if (c == '\n')
        break;
    if (c == EOF)
        break;

    s[i] = c;
}
```

Or if you're pretending that C doesn't have `break`, you can do something like this (this is not exactly equivalent because `i` doesn't have the same value if `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered):

```
for (i = 0; i < lim-1;)
{
    c = getchar();
    if (c == '\n')
        i = lim-1;
    else if (c == EOF)
        i = lim-1;
    else
        s[i++] = c;
}
```

Or you can use the Pascal approach:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
...
i = 0;
bool more = i < lim-1;

while (more)
{
    c = getchar();
    if (c == '\n')
        more = false;
    else if (c == EOF)
        more = false;
    else
    {
        s[i++] = c;
        more = i < lim-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did finally figure it out myself after thinking about it a bit further, though my solution is still more convoluted than yours and possibly still buggy. I am a bit frustrated that I was unable to see the solution to a seemingly simple problem and also was unable to use GDB effectively to step through the problem. I have used GDB in the past but am a bit rusty and simply could not remember or figure out how to enter the command line arguments AND print the variable values simultaneously even when I linked gdb to the pid of the executable.

Comment: Great response. Though that final solution wouldn't be allowable, as the task is to rewrite the loop without `||` and without `&&`.

Answer (score 4):

> but to my surprise it happily soldiers on

You have three nested loops. A newline would terminate one of the inner loops, while the outermost loop would happily carry on (until you've hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> `lim` times).

I can give you a hint: you probably shouldn't be using nested loops for this.

Comment: Duh! Thanks. I need to think about it for a moment but I suspect that reversing the logic of the inner loops to the outer loop may achieve the desired effect.

Comment: and think **if**

Answer (score 0):

With `goto`

```
i=0;
loop:
if( i >= lim - 1) goto end;
c = getchar();
if(c == '\n') goto end;
if(c == EOF) goto end;
s[i++] = c;
goto loop;
end:
```

Without `break`, `goto` and with just one `for`, still without `&&` and `||`.

```
for (i=0; i < lim - 1 ? ((c=getchar()) == '\n' | c == EOF) == 0 : 0; ++i)
  s[i] = c;
```

**Update**

As noted by @Jim it's way better to set order of execution explicitly by using internal `?:`

```
for (i=0; i >= lim - 1 ? 0 : (c=getchar()) == '\n' ? 0 : c != EOF; ++i)
  s[i] = c;
```

Comment: That second one will call `getchar` when `i == lim-1` because `|` doesn't short circuit. And even your first one is inaccurate, because 0 might already be > `lim-1`.

Comment: Of course - you are right. First one is typo, second, paying attention not too much.

Comment: It's still buggy because the order of evaluation of the two sides of `|` is not defined. Since you're using `?` `:` to emulate `||`, just do it for both tests ... e.g.,  `((c=getchar()) == '\n' ? 0 : c != EOF`

Comment: Easiest to read: `for (i=0; i >= lim-1 ? 0 : (c=getchar()) == '\n' ? 0 : c != EOF; ++i)
  s[i] = c;`