# How do I run GDB, enter text into the command line AND see how the executable treats those entries?

Tags: c++, c, linux, emacs, gdb

How do you run `GDB` while allowing interactive entry of characters from the command line while simultaneosuly "printing" the values of the variables arising from the parsed characters from those entries?

In other words how do I run gdb, enter text into the command line AND see how the executable treats those entries?

Also is there any difference in the behavior of gdb if I run it from within Emacs with `M-x gdb`? Suspending the executable with `C-c C-c` and then trying to print variable values does not behave like I expected. It did not seem to recognize valid variable values from the suspended executable being debugged. I did generate a "debuggable" excutable from `Clang` with `-ggdb -O0` flags.

I also tried to link gdb to the pid of the program executable running in a separate terminal but still am having difficulty with it. The program needs to parse command line entries interactively; I cannot pass them as initial command line arguments.

I hope I made my question clear.

Comment: With recent *emacs* and `M-x gdb` you have various Emacs "windows" to play with...

Answer (score 1):

After you started M-x gdb enter M-x gdb-many-windows . This opens new windows in your frame which show the stack, breakpoints, locals, your code and I/O of your program, meaning if you type there the input will be given to your executable.